# text-align: justify not working

Tags: html, css, text-align, justify

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">Commissions</a>
    <a href="#">Business Setup</a>
    <a href="#">Administrator</a>
    <a href="#">Content Management</a>
    <a href="#">Inventory</a>
    <a href="#">Communications Tools</a>
    <a href="#">Genealogy</a>
    <a href="#">Reports</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: justify;
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0066cc;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
#menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I want to make each links to have the whole width. I tried to implement so with text-align: justify. But it's not working. How can I do this?

Comment: You can only justify when there are multiple words, as it's made for flushing the edges of paragraphs.

I can't really tell what you're trying to achieve. Do you really want each <a> element to stretch across 1000px? Note: you probably want to add "display:block;" to "#menu a". Then you could add "letter-spacing: 50px;" or something to the "#menu a" elements, but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Do you want the text in your `<a>` elements to be all the same width?

Comment: No. All links have different length. But length between these links should be the same.

Comment: add a `margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;`?

Comment: @Jan. My question is about `text-align: justify`.

Comment: @Alexander.Plutov See http://jsfiddle.net/Flack/Q7z6q/. Does the result looks any similar to your desired one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No. All links have different length. But length between these links should be the same.

I have only a tables solution. http://jsfiddle.net/Flack/Q7z6q/

I know it's dirty and will be glad if someone comes with a better idea.

Answer (score 5):

This will make evenly spaced divs(can be links or about any element). The issue you ran in to is that justify doesn't work on a single line of text (or the last line of text). That is why you need the :after psuedo element.

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.wrapper{
  text-align: justify;
}
.wrapper div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper:after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I have been fretting over it for a day. Finally came here and the problem is solved.

Comment: @Solace Any more info you can provide? I use this everywhere, all day long as a replacement for bootsrap/grid systems so I can assure you it works.

Comment: @Solace This is the article that first inspired my to do my layouts in this manner: http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/

Comment: Thank you. I just posted a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686814/why-doesnt-this-text-alignjustified-work-other-so-questions-did-not-resolve-t). If you can have a look, I will appreciate that. =)

Comment: it will take 2 line I have to specify the height of `.wrapper` right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but by the sounds of things you want justify to do something that it was not designed to do.

Only when a line of text wraps at the right edge of a container will the text be justified.

This however, cannot really happen in your menu.

So instead of a justify fix (I say fix, although nothing is broken), I instead have another suggestion.

From my understanding you want your links evenly spread across your div.

The best way I can think of is to give the a elements a percentage based width based on the number of links and align to center instead of justify.

For example:

```
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0066cc;
    font-size: 9pt;
    width: 12%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I don't know if it is what you want but you can try it and see what you think.