# Why doesn't this text-align:justified work?

Tags: html, css, anchor, text-align

The problem I am facing is that inside a `div` having `text-align:justified;`, there is a bunch of `a` elements, on which the `text-align:justified` is Not working. So I wrote an SSCCE to demonstrate the problem, but to my surprise and frustration, it does work in the SSCCE.

I have used all my brain power to make the SSCCE as similar to the original code as possible, and they are like equivalent at this point. So I am posting the screenshots of both the pages, and also the code.

***PART OF ORIGINAL WEBSITE:***

[image]

The following mark-up is from the .php file, and this `<section>` has a `<div>` which has `position:relative; display:table;` and a few sibling `<section>` elements, each of which has `position:relative`. These are children of a `<div>` which also has `position:relative`, which is a child of `<body>` which doesn't have position or display property set, but has `height:100%`.

```
<section class="body-wrapper full-width">
    <div class="everything-wrapper fixed-width">
        <p class="desc-para">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <div class="links-wrapper">
            <?php //$num=1;
                foreach ($links as $a_link) {
                    echo '<a class="a-link" href="' . $a_link->the_url . '" target="_blank">';
                        echo '<div class="image-replace the-div" style="background-image:url(pix/colours.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;"  >';
                            echo 'just a link';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<p class="caption">Those angel eyes</p>';
                    echo '</a>';
                }
            ?>
        </div><!-- .links-wrapper -->
    </div><!-- .everything-wrapper -->
</section>
```

**CSS:** I copied and pasted the CSS to the SSCCE, so you can find it below in the code-editor; I am not posting it here because that would make the question longer for no good reason.

---

***SSCCE:***

[image]

```css
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section, details, summary {
    display: block;
}


section.body-wrapper {
 position:relative;
 background-color:teal;
 width:100%;
 min-width:960px;
}

div.fixed-width {
 width:960px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 padding:0px 10px;
}

.everything-wrapper p.desc-para {
 font-size:18px;
 width:460px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:40px 0px 27px;
}

div.links-wrapper {
 background-color:black;
 padding: 20px 0px 50px;
 text-align:justify;
}
div.links-wrapper:after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.a-link {
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
}

div.the-div {
 font: 0px/0 a;
 border: coral 2px solid;
 height:140px;
 width:140px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s
}

.the-div:hover {
 background-color:grey;
 border: coral 6px solid;
}

.caption {
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 padding-top:20px;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 font-weight:100;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.caption:hover {
 color:cyan;
 font-weight:200;
}
```

```html
<section class="body-wrapper">



 <div class="everything-wrapper fixed-width">
  <p class="desc-para">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

  <div class="links-wrapper">

   <a class="a-link" href="#">
    <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
    <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
   </a>

   <a class="a-link" href="#">
    <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
    <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
   </a>

   <a class="a-link" href="#">
    <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
    <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
   </a>

   <a class="a-link" href="#">
    <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
    <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
   </a>

   <a class="a-link" href="#">
    <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
    <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
   </a>

   <a class="a-link" href="#">
    <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(http://www.monitoryourheart.com/wcm/groups/mdtcom_sg/@mdt/@crdm/documents/images/icon-mri-50px.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Bulb</div>
    <p class="caption">Strangler Wrangler</p>
   </a>

  </div> <!-- .links-wrapper -->

 </div> <!-- .everything-wrapper -->



</section><!-- .body-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Where *didn't* it work?

Comment: Is the website live yet? In your screenshot, it looks like the `a` elements are floated to the left, which they aren't in the snippet.

Comment: @jerdiggity You see in the SSCCE, the `<a>`s are all "justified", that is there is equal distance between them and the first and last are on the left and right edge of the parent div respectively. That is not the case in the first screenshot.

Comment: @MrLister Nope it isn't live yet. There are No floats there, you can see in the CSS I posted. I also just checked in the firefox inspector.

Comment: @Solace yeah I saw that... Which browser was that first screenshot taken from?

Comment: @jerdiggity Firefox. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the problem is that in your live code you have no white space between the `a` elements, while in the SSCCE there are some. `text-align:justify` works by widening the white spaces, so if there are no white spaces it can't happen

Comment: Thank you. I wish I was that smart.

Comment: @Alohci good eye. It's easy to run into this problem on generated code.

Comment: @TorranceScott Yes, in the real code, the `<a>` elements were being generated by a for loop, and all I did was changed `</a>` to `</a> `, that is added a space after each anchor tag, which solved the problem.